# PHP change item in array coming from a database

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like so:

```
[0] => Array(
        [id] => 1602[title] => Title [image] => 140061419150image.jpg
    )
```

And I am generating this array from a database like so:

```
$results = array();
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                        /*if($row['image']){
                                $results[] = 'http://www.website.com/images/' . $row['image'];
                        }else{*/
                                $results[] = $row;
                        //}
                }
```

What I am trying to do now, as this data comes in and gets added to the array, if its image, I want to add on the full URL to it. I have tried the following commented out above and it only returned images and not any other data (id and title) I have also tried $row == 'image' but it return all the data, but add the url :(

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: it only returned the image because that is all you asked for.  if you want all the info then you need to call it specifically.

Comment: try this:

$results = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
if(! empty($row['image'])){
$results[] = 'http://www.website.com/images/' . $row['image'];
}else{
$results[] = $row;
}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In single iteration you are checking if it's image or not. If image, than you add full path of image to array and ignore rest of `$row`. To fix this, remove `else`:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
     if (!empty($row['image'])) { // check if there is set image for current row.
        $row['image'] = "http://www.website.com/images/{$row['image']}";
     }

     $results[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Justinas...I have no idea why I have so many downvotes :(